# Why can't objects made of insulating material "store excess charges"?

Tags: electric-fields, charge

This is quoted from my textbook.

I saw plastic objects before being able to store excess charges.

For example, if you rub paper against a plastic pole. Both will gain charges.

But in lab, I never saw people using plastic sphere as point source of charge or plastic plates to create uniform electric field.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret

Answer (score 1):

Well, insulators can store charge. It is just very difficult to get a noticeable amount of charge into an insulator, since they do not conduct electricity very well..

Comment: Indeed, "conductors" and "insulators" are a judgment of degree, rather than absolute qualities.